# Change French chapter name with polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia

After reading polyglossia documentation here is what I ended with

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\begin{document}
\gappto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\chaptername{CHANGED}}
\chapter{Test}
Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

but the chapter name has not changed.
What is wrong ?

Comment: You need to issue `\gappto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\chaptername{CHANGED}}` in the preamble. Move the line between `\setmainlanguage{french}` and `\begin{document}`

Comment: or add a `\selectlanguage{french}` after your redefinition, that will reset the caption names.

Comment: @Ulrike : this is the accepted comment. Your solution sticks to the question and allows to keep the \gappto... out of the preamble. Changing the chapter name only for some chapters is made possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is general setup, so it should be performed in the preamble, not in the document body.

A change to `\captionsfrench` will only take effect the next time a `\selectlanguage{french}` declaration is issued.

Since French is your main language, the declaration will be issued at begin document.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{french}
\gappto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\chaptername{CHANGED}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
Lorem ipsum.

\end{document}
```

[image]